# DOM path of elements for magento extension

Tags: html, magento, dom

We are trying to configure a magento extension to work and this requires "DOM path (ex: ".product-shop .add-to-box .btn-cart")"

As we are using a magento template these paths are different, I have had a look and tried various combinations however I cannot seem to get them correct and am hoping someone can take a look.

We require them for the Availability text and the Add to Cart text on our product pages.

The code is below, however it may be easier to just view the webpage (also incase i've missed a bit of the code!) : http://foscam-uk.com/indoor-cameras/mjpeg/foscam-fi8916w-white-wireless-ip-camera.html

```
<div class="product-option">
            <div class="alert-price">

    <p class="availability in-stock">Availability: <span>In stock</span></p>



    <div class="price-box">
                                                            <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-217">
                    <span class="price">£71.99</span>                </span>

        </div>


    <ul class="tier-prices product-pricing">
                    <li>

                                                            Buy 2 for <span class="price">£64.99</span> each                                    

                                    and&nbsp;<strong class="benefit">save&nbsp;10%
            </strong>

                    <span class="msrp-price-hide-message">
                            </span>


        </li>

        </ul>
                            </div>



                            <div class="product-options" id="product-options-wrapper">

    <dl>

<dt><label class="required"><em>*</em>Power Supply</label></dt>
<dd class="last">
    <div class="input-box">
        <ul id="options-21-list" class="options-list"><li><input type="radio" class="radio  validate-one-required-by-name product-custom-option" onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()" name="options[21]" id="options_21_2" value="41"  price="0" /><span class="label"><label for="options_21_2">United Kingdom (3 Pin Plug) </label></span><script type="text/javascript">$('options_21_2').advaiceContainer = 'options-21-container';$('options_21_2').callbackFunction = 'validateOptionsCallback';</script></li><li><input type="radio" class="radio  validate-one-required-by-name product-custom-option" onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()" name="options[21]" id="options_21_3" value="42"  price="0" /><span class="label"><label for="options_21_3">Europe (2 Pin Plug) </label></span><script type="text/javascript">$('options_21_3').advaiceContainer = 'options-21-container';$('options_21_3').callbackFunction = 'validateOptionsCallback';</script></li></ul>                                    <span id="options-21-container"></span>
                        </div>
</dd>
        </dl>


            <p class="required">* Required Fields</p>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('#product-options-wrapper dl'), ['last']);</script>
<div class="product-options-bottom">



    <div class="price-box">
                                                            <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-217_clone">
                    <span class="price">£71.99</span>                </span>

        </div>

    <div class="add-to-cart">
                <label for="qty">Qty:</label>
        <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="0" title="Qty" class="input-text qty" />
                <button type="button" title="Add to Basket" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span>Add to Basket</span></span></button>
            </div>


<ul class="add-to-links">

</ul>
</div>

                    </div>
```

Comment: I"m a pretty good magento developer, but I couldn't figure out what you're asking here.

Comment: Hello Alan, sorry for any confusion. Basically we have an extension which is meant to change the availability "In stock" text and the "Add To Cart" text on the button to "Backorder". In the magento backend it requires the DOM path for the : Add to Cart Button Element and Stock Status Label Element, I'm trying to figure out exactly what these are as we are using a template so they are not the original.